# ASP.NET MVC web app looping between fields only on some devices

Tags: html, typescript, asp.net-mvc, safari

[image: devtools screenshot]I'm not a developer but working with one to try and get a fix for my web application.

This specific issue is not happening on any desktop computer but appears to be happening on my MacBook Pro when using Safari (not Chrome) and my 5th Gen iPad in both Safari and Chrome.

When I access a specific section of the program, it begins to 'tab' through every field on that page endlessly. When I check the network log it states 'PerformValidationActions' appears to be in a loop cycling through 'text1_enter' 'text1_leave' 'text2_enter' 'text2_leave' 'text3_enter' 'text3_leave'  etc.  It EVENTUALLY ends but then when you try to log out you get the error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!